# how do I sort a collection with child property?

Tags: linq, linq-to-sql, entity-framework-4.1

I should sort parent based on a field of child.

sample code;

```
IQueryable<Parent> data = context.Parents.Include(o=>o.Children);
```

//Child has a member (string) Name.

question: how can I sort Parent by Children Names.

Answer (score 44, accepted):

Your question is somewhat confusing, since first of all, it is tagged both with Entity Framework and LINQ-to-SQL. Which ORM are your actually using?

Secondly, and more to the point, you say that you want to `"sort Parent by Children Names"`. Which child name do you want to sort by? You do realize that you can't compare a **list** of names to another **list** of names and decide which one should come before the other?

So if I assume you want to sort by the child name that comes first lexicographically, your solution would be the following (@Paul was close on this one, but you need to specify the property you are sorting by):

```
context.
Parents.
OrderBy(p => p.
             Children.
             OrderBy(c => c.Name).Select(c => c.Name).FirstOrDefault()
       );
```

In this case, consider the following setup. Parent `PA` has children `CB` and `CD` while parent `PB` has children `CC` and `CA`. As a result of the sorting, parent `PB` will come first in the sorted list, since child `CA` will be used as the "main" child for `PB`, while `CB` will be the "main" child for `PA`. If that's not the behavior you are looking for, please provide an example and a clearer description.

Answer (score 5):

You can take one of the children names to sort by, probably select it by doing the corresponding sorting?

Something like:

```
IQueryable<Parent> data = context.Parents.OrderBy(
     p=>p.Children.OrderBy(chi => chi.Name).FirstOrDefault());
```

Comment: hi Paul. this linq throwed exception; "DbSortClause expressions must have a type that is order comparable.
Parameter name: key"

Comment: Can you probably try the approach described here: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/adodotnetentityframework/thread/3b26c018-a6e5-4cf4-9547-744991ff5ada

Comment: @NuriYILMAZ that's because after `FirstOrDefault()` you need to get the property or column as well such as `FirstOrDefault().MyProperty1`.